# %d for unsigned integer

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I accidentally used "%d" to print an unsigned integer using an online compiler. I thought errors would pop out, but my program can run successfully. It's good that my codes are working, but I just don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x = 1;

    printf( "%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the "unsigned integer" was small enough that the MSB (most significant bit) was not set. If it were, printf() would have treated the value as a "negative signed integer" value.

```
int main() {
    uint32_t x = 0x5;
    uint32_t y = 0xC0000000;

    printf( "%d  %u  %d\n", x, y, y );

    return 0;
}
```

```
5  3221225472  -1073741824
```

You can see the difference.

With *new-fangled* compilers that "read into" printf format specifiers and match those with the datatypes of following parameters, it may be that the online compiler may-or-may-not have been able to report this type mismatch with a warning. This may be something you will want to look into.

Comment: According to [§7.21.6.1 ¶9 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9), if the argument is not of the correct type, the behavior is undefined. The `%d` conversion format specifier requires an argument of type `int`, not `unsigned int`. Therefore, as far as the standard is concerned, you cannot rely on the behavior specified in your answer. However, I am still upvoting your answer, because I am unaware of any modern [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform) on which the behavior differs from the behavior specified in your answer.

Comment: Note that `%u` is the conversion format specifier for `unsigned int`, but not necessarily for `uint32_t`. To find the conversion format specifer for `uint32_t`, the portable way is to use the macro [`PRIu32`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Comment: Actually, I am unsure myself what the best code for your answer would be. On the one hand, using a fixed-width integer type is useful, in order to be sure that you are setting the MSB. On the other hand, `%u` should not be used with fixed-width integer types.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, so what would be the GCC parameter to enable such a warning?

Comment: @0andriy: The compiler GCC will not warn you about using `%d` instead of `%u`, even when using `-Wall -Wextra`. I believe that is because on all platforms supported by that compiler, it will simply behave as if the `unsigned int` were converted to a `signed int`.

Comment: The most portable way would be to `#include <inttypes.h>` and to write `printf( "%"PRIu32"  %"PRIu32"  %"PRId32"\n", x, y, y );` instead of `printf( "%d  %u  %d\n", x, y, y );`. On platforms on which `int` is 32 bits wide, `PRIu32` will probably expand to `u` and `PRId32` will probably expand to `d`. However, I'm not sure if I recommend using thoese macros, because that will make your answer harder to read and understand.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, it seems you misunderstood my question. I think `-Wformat-signedness` is what should enable that (haven't tried yet, though).

Comment: @0andriy: Yes, you are correct. According to my tests on GCC, `-Wformat-signedness` does provide a warning if you use `%d` for `unsigned int`. It seems that warning is not enabled by default, even if you use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 0):

refer to [printf() manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), they said:

> A character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied. The
> conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **d, i**
>
> The int argument is
> converted to signed decimal notation. The precision, if any, gives the
> minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value
> requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with zeros. The
> default precision is 1. When 0 is printed with an explicit precision
> 0, the output is empty.

so it means that the parameter even if it's in `unsigned` representation, it will be converted into its `signed int` representation and printed, see the following code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    signed int x1 = -2147483648;
    unsigned int x2 = -2147483648;
    unsigned long long x3 = -2147483648;

    printf("signed int x1 = %d\n", x1);
    printf("unsigned int x2 = %d\n", x2);
    printf("signed long long x3 = %d\n", x3);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
signed int x1 = -2147483648
unsigned int x2 = -2147483648
signed long long x3 = -2147483648
```

so it means no matter what is the type of the variable printed, as long as you specified `%d` as format specifier, the variable will be converted into its representation in `signed int` and be printed

in case of `unsigned char` like for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char s = -10;

    printf("s = %d",s);
}
```

the output is :

```
s = 246
```

as the binary representation of `unsigned char s = -10` is :

```
1111 0110
```

where the MSB bit is 1, but when it's converted into `signed int`, the new representation is :

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 0110
```

so the MSB is no longer have that 1 bit in its MSB which represents whether the number is positive or negative.

Comment: `printf` does not convert anything for `%d`. Any arguments narrower than `int` will be converted to `int` as part of the argument promotions, so a `char` or `unsigned char` passed for `%d` will be promoted to `int` (in ordinary C implementations) before `printf` sees them. A `float` or `long long` passed to `printf` will not be converted to `int`, and `%d` will generally not work for them. The “conversion” `printf` performs is to convert from the argument value to a character string, such as the number in an `int` to a decimal numeral in a character string.

Comment: Passing `unsigned int` for `%d` has undefined behavior according to the C standard. It often “works” in C applications because of a strong correspondence between signed and unsigned types of the same rank, including how the ABI treats them. But it does not “work” because of any conversion performed by `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

> [9](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9) The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each type is the same.41)

> [41](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note41)) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions

> [7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types ... a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object

It looks like it is not undefined behaviour to pass an unsigned integer where a signed integer is expected, or vice versa, as long as the value is representable in both types.

Perhaps it is not a coincidence that no existing compiler warns about this particular mismatch even at the highest warning level.